# Finding the smallest number $a \geq 0$ such that $a \equiv 7^{83} \bmod 11$.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

> Find the smallest number $a \geq 0$ such that $a \equiv 7^{83} \bmod 11$.

I know that I am supposed to come to the conclusion $a = 2$, but I don't understand how I reach this conclusion using Fermat's or Euler's theorem.

I have the order $83$ to $7$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$, but I don't know what I write as an answer, because writing just $a = 2$ is not enough to show that I have understood how I came to the answer without using a calculator to just calculate that $7^{83} \bmod 11 = 2$.

Comment: What does Fermat's Little Theorem say about $7^{10} \pmod {11}$?

Comment: with numbers of this size even python is enough to get the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> According to [Fermat's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) $$a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$$ for prime $p\nmid a$.

Therefore, $$7^{83} =\color{red}{(7^{11-1})}^8\cdot 7^3 \equiv \color{red}1\cdot 7^3 \equiv 343 \equiv 2\pmod {11}$$ Hence, $a=2$.